# Why is my moving rectangle on a JPanel vibrating at fixed intervals?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, motion

I created a program that draws and moves a rectangle but it vibrates approx. every 15 seconds.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
}
Game() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
void start() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
public void run() {
    while (true) {  
        x++;
        y++;

        repaint();  
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
}
}
```

**Questions**

- Why is the rectangle vibrating while moving?
- How do I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing swing components from any thread other than the event dispatch thread. Use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to schedule tasks.

Comment: `paintComponent` can be called for any number of reasons.  `repaint` requests can also be consolidated down to a single (or lesser) actual events.  Any of these combinations could be causing you issues

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).